# Closed form for infinite sum over Hermite polynomial $H_{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form, hermite-polynomials

I am looking for a closed form of the following infinite sum
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\ (r)_n }{(2n)!} w^{2n}H_{2n}(z)$$
I found a similar formula on [Wolfram](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/HermiteH/23/02/0004/) as
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(r)_n }{(2n)!} w^{2n}H_{2n}(z)=(w^2+1)^{-c} \ _1 F_1\left(c;\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2 w^2}{w^2+1}\right)$$
Unfortunaly I don't know what to do with $\left(n-\frac{1}{2} \right)!$!! Is there a closed formula for this series, or an approximation.

Comment: If $r>0$ sum is divergent ?